# Interpreting error when trying to import dta file in R

Tags: r, dataset, stata

I'm trying to solve a couple of exercises in Gelman and Hill 2007.

The datasets they use are all on a website, however, every time I try to import the files I get an error:

> pollution=read.table("pollution.dta")
>   Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>     line 1 did not have 2 elements

Here's the dataset: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/pollution/

I guess there's a problem with the datasets, but I'm wondering if there's a modification that could enable me to import it?

Comment: For the record, because it's not clear on that Web site, this .dta file is in Stata format.  It has no apparent problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the read.dta in the foreign library

```
library("foreign")
ds <- read.dta(file.choose())
```

it worked when I tried with your dta file.